# How can I remove this Git helper button bar in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode (Version 1.28.2) for MacOS and I have this really annoying bar I can't seem to remove.

Close Up of bar:

[image: Close up of bar]

Wider View:

[image]

If anyone has some insight on how to hide this, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did this button/toolbar come by default with VSCode or have you installed an extension (if yes, what is it's name)? If you don't want to use the git integration on VSCode at all, you can disable it by adding the line `"git.enabled": false` to your `settings.json`. The button then should disappear.

Comment: The git icon probably comes from the `donjayamanne.githistory` extension. I would guess that the others are from extensions as well, with the exception of split windows and the '...'

Comment: It's a shame the git extension doesn't have a setting to show/hide those buttons.  Real estate in any ide is precious, imho no extension should add a button there unless it can be hidden through a setting.  Any functionality offered by a button can (and should) also be made available in the command palette.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [davedeecoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7388458/davedeecoder), seems like you have enabled [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory), so in order to remove the bar you need to disable the extension by adding the line "git.enabled": false to your settings.json. IF you are unable to disable it, unfortunately, you have to **Uninstall** it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable this the following way:

- Bring up the command prompt (Cmd-shift-P on Mac)
- Enter Install Extensions
- Search for `@builtin` in the Explorer of Extensions
- Disable the Git extension
- Reload the Editor as it suggests.